# AJAX call to Mediawiki API & retrieving information from wikipedia page

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, mediawiki

I'm super new to AJAX, APIs and JSON so apologies. I'm trying to retrieve the top songs from this [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_top_10_singles_in_2000). I console logged the results and I get the title and a bunch of text. But none of the text includes the main content of the page. Am I not using the correct API format to make a specific enough call? How should I effectively dissect the information from the object that I returned?

Here's my AJAX call:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text|sections&section=0&page=List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_top_10_singles_in_2000&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `section=0` means parse the part before the first section (up to the first heading), which is exactly what the API does.

Answer (score 0):

As Tgr says, `section=0` returns the first section on the page, which in this case is a banner template plus the text "This is a list of singles that charted in the top ten of the Billboard Hot 100 during 2000".

To get all the page, use the URL https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_top_10_singles_in_2000. Or if you want just the list with the data in, use `section=1`: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text|sections&section=1&page=List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_top_10_singles_in_2000. (Be aware that the section number can change at any time if someone edits the page, though.)